# How to add entered odd numbers using while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to make a while loop that adds only odd numbers that I entered.
I wrote some codes but they keep adding the last entered even number too.
I know that it would be much easier if I use an if-statement, but I just want to make a code that works with a while loop.
Here is my code.

```
package loop_example;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhileEx03 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an odd number");
    int input = scanner.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    sum += input;
    System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
            
    while (input%2 == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter an odd number.");
        input = scanner.nextInt();
        sum += input;
        System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
    }
    System.out.println("Finished.");
  }
}
```

Comment: you can't do this with a while loop without an if. Just think about it. what you have now, will only execute until you enter an even number, and it'll add that.

Comment: @Stultuske Oh I got it!! Thanks.

Comment: @Stultuske You can do it with a while loop and without an if, see my answer. But it's a utterly stupid thing to do.

Comment: @maio290 yes, but again, your answer doesn't meet the criteria. it would stop running after a few following even numbers are entered, that's not what he wants

Comment: @Stultuske That would still be possible - but I guess we has using it as an exit condition intentionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is the following:

```
sum += input;
```

You have to check the input before adding it to the sum:

```
 if(input%2 == 1) sum += input;
```

Actually, you don't need to have the first block of statements, it's enough to do it in a modified loop:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    boolean evenNumberEntered = false;
    
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter an odd number: ");
        try 
        {
            int input = scanner.nextInt();
            
            if(input % 2 == 1) sum += input;
            else evenNumberEntered = true;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {}
        
    } while(!evenNumberEntered);
```

If you really insist on doing this with a while loop, it would be possible - but to be frank, that code is shitty:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an odd number");
    int input = scanner.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    
    
    while(input%2 == 1)
    {
        sum += input;
        break;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
            
    while (input%2 == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter an odd number.");
        input = scanner.nextInt();
        while(input%2 == 1)
        {
            sum += input;
            break;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
    }
```